# Design pattern for a context sensitive popup menu in a ListActivity

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity with row defined as this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/me_games_won"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/gamesmate_username"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/him_games_won"
     android:textSize="16sp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageMenuGamesmate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />     
</LinearLayout>
```

The image is used to popup or not a menu depending on some status of the row. 
My ArrayAdapter has this piece of code to launch the popup menu:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
myimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu_gamesmate, popupMenu.getMenu());
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

return true;
}
});

popupMenu.show();               
}               
});
```

Now when the user clicks on the menu item, an action will be performed but the values of the row are required to format the request properly.

I am looking for the best design pattern to do this?

Maybe subclassing the row view of the ListView of the ListActivity, but how then?
Maybe subclassing the PopupMenu in order for it to keep a version of the data used to create the row?
etc...

Anyone with a good idea?

Cheers.
David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible YAGNI-based approach.

1. To popup or not? I believe you have no problem with this.  You have all the data handy in your getView(). So a simple if() seems to be sufficient there.
2. Assuming your popup menu is always the same, only the action is varied depending on the data, you only need to make the menu data-aware. To achieve that, you need to have a reference to the corresponding data item in onMenuItemClick().  To get it there, you could:

   - Subclass the popup menu
   - Pass the position to the menu's custom constructor
   - Use the position in onMenuItemClick() to retrieve the data item via adapter.getItem(int position) and apply any desired logic there

The benefit of this approach is minimalism.  You only pass an integer around.

PS. In addition, you can encapsulate stuff nicely if you wish.

PPS. If you need a variety of popup menus, you can create a factory that knows how to make the right subclass when called from getView().

Comment: This is what I had in mind... Not the nicest pattern but will achieve its result.
By the way, do you know how to access the Activity from a PopupMenu? I want the request to the server been initiated from the Activity.

Comment: If the other classes are inner classes within your activity, use MyActivity.this. Otherwise, it's OK to pass the Activity around, e.g., as yet another constructor/method parameter. Just beware of activity leaks. They can happen if you keep references to the activity in some objects that outlive it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the listview with an adapter? This will make it very easy to be handled, there are many examples on how to do this (ex. http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)